# Access Google+ Page Platform Insights via API

Tags: google-api, google-plus

How do I get access to insights data for my Google+ Page via API?

We can connect it with Google API console, to activate insights tab, but after days of "googlng" I could not find any API that gives me reliable data about my own page.

There seems to be no such API, but I couldn't believe it since FB has a great API for all data thats shown on its own dashboard.

Am I looking at wrong place, or searching for wrong thing!  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is not an API to provide the level of detail that you desire. You could use some of the data returned via the `activities` methods, but it wouldn't give you insights about things like interactive posts or sign-in.